# how to return fields in json as they are wroted in class?

Tags: c#, json, .net, swagger

I should return an object:

**Side C#**

```
public class teste
   {
       public Guid TechnicalId { get; set; }
       public string UVBa { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
       public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
   }
```

**what is returned side Swagger:**

```
{
"technicalId": "f01d7c2c-db03-4eeb-9e0f-80c71a94eb4c",
"uvBa": "test",
"name": "teste",
"startDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
"endDate": "2021-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

As you see fields are in camelCase, I want to represent them as they are written in my code, is there a way ? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[JsonProperty]` in this way:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

[JsonProperty("uvBa")]
public string UVBa { get; set; }
```

Reference [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)